# {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"} for Spotify API

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api, spotify-app

Using Spotify Documentation for Client Credential Flow
(https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization/client-credentials/)

I was able to create an API request in JavaScript:

```
function getoAuth () {
    const client_id = id;
    const client_secret = secret;
    fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Authorization': 'Basic' + (client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString('base64')
        },
        form: {
            grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        },
        json: true
        
    })
  }
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

> {"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}

Why is this failing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the fetch library docs, you have to pass the formdata through body field.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/fetch

```js
 fetch("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
           'Authorization': 'Basic<>'
        },
        body: new URLSearchParams({
            'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
        }),
        json: true
        
    })
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I updated my code and ran it, but I'm still getting the same error